# Nginx - UWSGI 504 gateway timeout

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

I saw lots of topics of `nginx` 504 error , but non if them solved this.

Im using `nginx` , `uwsgi` on 1 machine to run `Django` application .

i tried to add these config line at the end of `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` :

```
uwsgi_read_timeout 3s;

uwsgi_connect_timeout 75s;
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
send_timeout                600s;
```

in these settings `uwsgi_read_timeout` is 3 seconds and `nginx` will raise 504 error at 3 seconds . so it works BUT when i change it to `uwsgi_read_timeout 60s;` then The 504 error raises in 30 seconds .

it seems there is an upstream timeout that causes this error !

How can i solve this ?